# drupal menu wildcard auto-loader is called multiple times

Tags: drupal, wildcard, drupal-hooks, hook-menu

I am working on a drupal6 site, there is an custom module with a menu walidcard auto-loader like following

```
$items['admin/content/quest/%quest'] = array(                                                                       |
'title' => 'Quest',                                                                                               |
'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),                                                     |function quest_admin_view($quest){
'page callback' => 'quest_admin_view',                                                                            |  dsm($quest);
'page arguments' => array(3),                                                                                     |  quest_build_content($quest);
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,                                                                                          |  quest_invoke_questapi($quest, 'alter');
'file' => 'quest.admin.inc',                                                                                      |  quest_invoke_questapi($quest, 'admin_view');
);
```

Problem is that wildcard loader quest_load is called more than 6 times, I couldn't figure out what is problem in this menu item.

Comment: Your menu callback looks fine - Do you have other MENU_LOCAL_TASK's added with same parent ?

Comment: Yes, there are some more MENU_CALLBACK and MENU_LOCAL_TASK types of menu paths registered as 'admin/content/quest/' as parent.